# returning a java.util.List in a Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, client-server, apache-axis, xmlbeans

I try to create a Bottom up Java bean Web Service in eclipse  and I need to return a `java.util.List` so I have this on the server

```
public class BookStoreWS {
    private Book book1;
    private List<Book> listOfBooks;

    public Book getBook(){
        return  book1;
    }
    public List<Book> getBooks(){
        return  listOfBooks;
    }
}
```

and this on the client

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BookStoreWSStub stub = new BookStoreWSStub();
    GetBookResponseDocument gbrd = stub.getBook();
    Book book = gbrd.getGetBookResponse().getReturn();//OK

    GetBooksResponseDocument gbrd2 = stub.getBooks();
    XmlObject OMGIAMNOTALIST = gbrd2.getGetBooksResponse().getReturn();//BAD
}
```

So `getBook()` returns my desired object `Book` but `getBooks()` returns `XmlObject` instead of a `List<Book>`

Any easy way of getting a `List<Book>` instead of a `XmlObject`? Or to transform the `XmlObject` into a `List<Book>`?

Comment: I think you need provide more details.

Comment: What do you need? I tryed to simplify it as much as possible..

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for?

```
List<A> OMGIAMALIST = new ArrayList<A>();
OMGIAMALIST.addAll(stub.getAs());

for ( A item : OMGIAMALIST ) {
    XmlObject OMGIAMANITEM = item.getGetAsResponse().getReturn();
}
```

`XmlObject` (most probably) cannot be an A, but item surely is.